# node-gyp rebuild fails while installing node modules

Tags: node.js, xslt, node-gyp

I am trying to install node_xslt module in node 0.12 but it is failing. I have python version 2.7 and node-gyp version 2.0.2.

Here is the error stack-

```
> node_xslt@0.1.9 preinstall /home/ritesh/Ritesh/projects/applane1/node_modules/node_xslt
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: xml2-config: not found
gyp: Call to 'xml2-config --cflags' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ritesh/Ritesh/projects/applane1/node_modules/node_xslt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node_xslt"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node_xslt@0.1.9 preinstall: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node_xslt@0.1.9 preinstall script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node_xslt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node_xslt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /node_modules/npm-debug.log
```

This error comes while installing other modules as well i.e. xslt4node.

Comment: according to your log install is using `gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3` not `2.0.2` as you expected

Answer (score 10):

Just had the same problem, though the question is 5+ years old, might be useful for somebody else. I solved my problem switching to a different version of node with nvm: `nvm use 12` in my case.

Comment: I solved the same issue by upgrading the version of node from 12 to the current LTS (which as of now is 14)

Comment: As of this writing 15.0.1 succeeded while 16.3.0 failed. It failed with this: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2

Comment: Worked for me, downgraded from v16

Answer (score 2):

Try installing compile tools

```
sudo apt-get install python3 g++ make python3-pip
```

Works for me

Comment: Helped me to overcome the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`

Comment: It doesn't work. I think, this problem is due to node-gyp. This error is coming while installing many node modules.